# configure shiny server with nginx

Tags: r, nginx, shiny

I am trying to configure nginx to redirect requests to a shiny server. before this configuration shiny server and all the apps work fine, but when I tried to use the following script in the nginx some functions of shiny is broken.
here is my nginx config

```
   rewrite ^/shiny$ $scheme://$http_host/shiny/ permanent;

    location /shiny/ {
      rewrite ^/shiny/(.*)$ /$1 break;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3838;
      proxy_redirect / $scheme://$http_host/shiny/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_read_timeout 20d;
      proxy_buffering off;
    }
```

using above script all the requests to the `url/shiny/` are redirected to the shiny server but I have faced two error. 
Then an error with with odbc driver appears, which means it can not find driver

```
Warning in odbcDriverConnect(st, believeNRows = F) :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 0, message [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/nz/lib/libnzsqlodbc3.so' : file not found
Warning in odbcDriverConnect(st, believeNRows = F) :
```

if I disable nginx everything works fine. I tried to set user parameter in nginx but did not work.
Any idea how I can fix this issue?

Comment: I can't imagine why including `nginx` into the pipe would have an effect on `odbc` inside an R process (though I understand that you believe this). Are your shiny apps relying on any envvars or connection information? Authentication?

Comment: @r2evans thanks for the reply, no they are not related to anything, I am only using `dsn` name which is defined in `odbc.ini`, That file exists in that directory, I think that might be something related to user access. another thing is that it works fine when nginx is disabled.

Comment: Interesting problem, MajidHajati, I'm afraid I don't know how to help.

Comment: @r2evans well thanks, I think I have to investigate more to see what causes this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it turned out that `nginx` has conflict with `netezzaodbc` driver and we need to install that driver again.